# How to send base64 string to server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, base64, nsurlsession

I am working in an application in which I have to send `image` to the `server`, I am trying to send `Image` to `server` but in return I am getting

> BAD REQUEST 400

. Please tell me how do I resolve this error.

This method is use to convert image into base64 string

```
 NSData * imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.5);

 NSString * base64String = [imagedata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength

-(void)temp
{

      NSString * str=[self base64return];
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{

                               @"name": @"image_name",
                               @"img_data":str
                               };

    NSData * postData   = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                                                          options:kNilOptions error:nil];


    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxx/finalresult1"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];



    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                  {
                                      if (error == nil)
                                      {
                                          // Success
                                          NSLog(@"URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP %ld", ((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response).statusCode);





                                          NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:
                                                             NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                          NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                          NSLog(@"erroer is %@",error);
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          // Failure
                                          NSLog(@"URL Session Task Failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                      }
                                  }];
    [task resume];

}
```

Comment: how you convert `UIImage` to `base64` string?

Comment: Your code is right.. but you have to check image_data key data type on server side. It should be string only.

Comment: @singapore Yes I am sending string only

Comment: What about image_data data type on server side ? did you check

Comment: @kuldeep I have updated my code, please see

Comment: @AnshulKhare, `UIImage` to `Base64` code is fine, double check **img_data** data_type from server side. wether it's string or else?

Answer (score 1):

Change request Content-Type, Use:
         `[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`